# Django: [email protected] in admin

Tags: python, django

I'm having a seemingly simple problem, but I haven't found a way to debug it.

In the admin on our production website, when editing an object that has a ForeignKey to User, all the users show up as **[email protected]**. That makes the admin unusable in these areas!

I tried googling the problem, but because the term "email protected" appears in many mailing lists in an unrelated context, I can't find a solution. Also, I searched for "email protected" in the Django codebase but I didn't find it.

Any idea what to do?

Comment: did you look at the installed django modules to see if it's in there too?  

i wouldn't be surprised if there was some 3rd party module that is causing this.

Comment: I just checked the current stable release (1.4.1), I can't find anything in the codebase either. What version of Django is running on your production?

Comment: What does your users __unicode__ function look like? Does it return the users mailadress?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't really know the answer but whenever I see **[email protected]** showing up on Google, if I navigate to the link then the email shows up and if I inspect the element it has near it this piece of javascript:

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l=document.getElementById("__cf_email__");a=l.className;if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
```

This may help you further. (Inspect your element to see if this applies to you too.)

If you see it in your code too then [This](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/sql-ijection-or-something-have-i-been-hacked) and [this](http://just-ask-kim.com/autoresponse-plus-arp3-email-protected-error/#.UEEo0PEiGRA) may help you.

**EDIT:** It seems that it is caused by [Cloudflare's email obfuscation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170016-What-is-Email-Address-Obfuscation-).

Comment: Man, I've wasted an entire hour investigating this. Thanks for confirming my suspicions.

Comment: Same problem here with CloudFlare. Just went to https://www.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-settings?z=YOURDOMAIN.com#page=security and turn off email obfuscation.

Comment: You can disable this in cloudflare by adding a page rule regexing for your admin site url and then selecting "email obfuscation off"

Answer (score 1):

Email obfuscation is good thing for public site, and I would like to disable it for admin. So I write this middleware to disable email obfuscation in admin.

```
def _insert_email_off(html):
    origin = html
    try:
        pos1 = html.index('>', html.index('<body')) + 1
        html = html[:pos1] + '<!--email_off-->' + html[pos1:]
        pos2 = html.index('</body>')
        html = html[:pos2] +'<!--/email_off-->' + html[pos2:]
    except ValueError:
        return origin
    return html


class CloudflareEmailProtect(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if request.path.startswith('/admin/'):
            response.content = smart_bytes(_insert_email_off(smart_text(response.content)))
        return response


class TestCloudflareEmailProtect:

    def test_admin(self, rf):
        request = rf.get('/admin/aaa')
        html = '<html><body>content</body>'
        response = CloudflareEmailProtect().process_response(request, HttpResponse(html))
        assert b'<!--email_off--' in response.content

    def test_not_admin(self, rf):
        request = rf.get('/public')
        html = '<html><body>content</body>'
        response = CloudflareEmailProtect().process_response(request, HttpResponse(html))
        assert b'<!--email_off--' not in response.content


def test_insert_email_off():
    html = 'aa <body zzz>bb cc</body>dd'
    result = _insert_email_off(html)
    assert result == 'aa <body zzz><!--email_off-->bb cc<!--/email_off--></body>dd'

    assert _insert_email_off('aaa') == 'aaa'
```

Comment: you can just disable it thru Page Rules on cloudflare dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem ans wasted so many times for solution.
Finally,I solved this problem, by adding simply.

## Option-1:

Add in HTML page

```
<!--email_off-->YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS<!--/email_off-->
```

The Issue is mainly for the "Cloudflare obfuscating email".

## Option-2:

Deactivate from dashbaord.

1. Log in to the Cloudflare dashboard.
2. Ensure the website you want to verify is selected.
3. Click the Scrape Shield app.
4. Under Email Address Obfuscation, check that the toggle is set to On.

Comment: For details please check Cloudflare Link: [https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170016-What-is-Email-Address-Obfuscation-]